# Is there a way to activate a subset of nodes using tidygraph?

Tags: r, tidygraph

I am very new to `R`.

I am trying to code the following using tidygraph:

```
V(g)$activated <- F
V(g)[seeds]$activated=T
```

where `g` is my graph, `activated` is the attribute I want to add, `seeds` is a predefined vector. I am successful in doing the first part using `tidygraph`:

```
g%<>%activate(nodes)%>%
  mutate(activated=F)
```

I was wondering how to do the second part.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your `seeds` variable looks like. This solution assumes `seeds` is a numeric vector corresponding to node names. Here is the code to reproduce your graph.

```
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)

g <- play_erdos_renyi(10, .2)
seeds <- 1:3
V(g)$activated <- FALSE
V(g)[seeds]$activated <- TRUE
g

# # A tbl_graph: 10 nodes and 16 edges
# #
# # A directed simple graph with 1 component
# #
# # Node Data: 10 x 1 (active)
# activated
# <lgl>    
# 1 TRUE     
# 2 TRUE     
# 3 TRUE     
# 4 FALSE    
# 5 FALSE    
# 6 FALSE    
# # ... with 4 more rows
# #
# # Edge Data: 16 x 2
# from    to
# <int> <int>
# 1     8     1
# 2     4     2
# 3     1     3
# # ... with 13 more rows
```

Here is the solution. `row_number()` was used because node names correspond to row numbers in this random graph example. If you have a variable for node names, you can simply replace `row_number()`. On a separate note, `tidygraph` sets active the dataframe for nodes by default. So, no need to activate nodes.

```
g <- play_erdos_renyi(10, .2)
g |> 
  mutate(activated = row_number() %in% seeds)
  
# # A tbl_graph: 10 nodes and 16 edges
# #
# # A directed simple graph with 1 component
# #
# # Node Data: 10 x 1 (active)
# activated
# <lgl>    
# 1 TRUE     
# 2 TRUE     
# 3 TRUE     
# 4 FALSE    
# 5 FALSE    
# 6 FALSE    
# # ... with 4 more rows
# #
# # Edge Data: 16 x 2
# from    to
# <int> <int>
# 1     8     1
# 2     4     2
# 3     1     3
# # ... with 13 more rows
```